# Exception error while installing NLTK in Ubuntu 14.4 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, nltk

I got following error while installing NLTK when i run this command

`sudo pip install -U nltk`

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    name, None, isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 181, in from_line
    isolated=isolated)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 54, in init
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2873, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s)) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/init.py", line 2807, in parse_requirements
    raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '\xe2\x80\x90U')
```

Comment: You missed the last part of the exception. Can we see all the output of the command up to the traceback, as well, please?

Comment: only this is what i get when i run that command

Comment: It appears as if you have a local file with the contents `‐U` that is confusing `pip`. I don't have much time right now to figure out more though.

Comment: I have included screen shot of command outputs in bellow links

Comment: sudo easy_install pip   http://tinypic.com/?t=postupload

Comment: sudo pip install -U nltk
 http://tinypic.com/r/zogxw6/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you've cut and pasted this line from some web page (or PDF). The web page probably changed the [ASCII hyphen (minus sign)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/minus-sign-hyphen-ascii-code-45.html) into a [U+2010 HYPHEN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm).

Therefore, you need to type the command as

```
sudo pip install -U nltk   # This uses the usual ASCII hyphen
```

Do *not* cut-and-paste:

```
sudo pip install ‐U nltk   # This uses U+2010 HYPHEN
```

---

The error message

```
raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '\xe2\x80\x90U')
```

implies that `line` is the string `'\xe2\x80\x90U'`.

This utf-8 encoded string *looks like* a hyphen and a U:

```
In [90]: print('\xe2\x80\x90U')
‐U
```

but note that the hypen is not the usual ASCII hypen (`chr(45)`).
Rather, it is the utf-8 encoded U+2010 HYPHEN:

```
In [93]: import unicodedata as UD

In [95]: UD.name('\xe2\x80\x90'.decode('utf-8'))
Out[95]: 'HYPHEN'

In [102]: hex(ord('\xe2\x80\x90'.decode('utf-8')))
Out[102]: '0x2010'
```

as opposed to the usual hyphen, `chr(45)`, which is (the utf-8 encoded) [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm):

```
In [97]: UD.name('-'.decode('utf-8'))
Out[97]: 'HYPHEN-MINUS'

In [4]: hex(ord('-'.decode('utf-8')))
Out[4]: '0x2d'

In [98]: ord('-')
Out[98]: 45
```